# i wrote a code with python for hoop wiht computer but i can't end it when time up

Tags: python

hello i wrote a code with python for 'hoop' with computer and as long as it continues, the user loses
but i have a problem , I set a time limit for the input but after the time is up the program does not end, how i can fix it?

my code is :

```
from threading import Timer

print('Hello\nLets plat hoop!!!!\nYou hvae 5 seconds for each turn! - Tyepe * instead of hoop! ')
hoop_cycle_lenght = int(input('Please insert cycle lenght (a number): '))

count = 0
while True:
    count += 1
    if count % 2 == 0 :
        timer = Timer(5.0 , print , ['Sorry time up'])
        timer.start()
        user_chice = input('Your choice: ')
        timer.cancel()
        if count % hoop_cycle_lenght == 0 and count != 0:
            if user_chice == '*':
                pass
            else:
                print('You do mistake!\nGame over!!!')
                break
        else:
            user_chice = int(user_chice)
            if user_chice == count: 
                pass
            else:
                print('You do mistake!\nGame over!!!')
                break
    else:
        if count % hoop_cycle_lenght == 0 and count != 0:
            print('Computer choice: hoop!')
        else:
            print('Computer choice:' , count)
```

Comment: Tangentially, spell check your variables.

Comment: Please improve the spelling, this is not for our conveniece, one of your variables could easily be mispelled.

Comment: For many IDEs there are also plugins for spell checking

Answer (score 1):

`input()` pauses the program and waits for the user input.

The best solution for this would probably be an extra thread that reads inputs and stores them in an instance variable. So the main thread can check it.
A bit like with key events in curses with getch() or probably a similar implementation in pygame.
You could encounter problems with print though, because print() is not threadsave.

Another solution is some kind of timeout that interrupts the input.

I wrote something like this after a lengthy search for a solution:

```py
class TimeoutHelper(Thread):
    '''
    A helper class for the measurement of timeouts

    The function that should have the timeout gets defined and handed over to the 
    constructor of this class. This function has to return two values. The first 
    has to be True or the returned value of the defined function and the second 
    Value has to be false or the error the defined function raises.
    Then the timer() method of this class is called with the length of the timeout 
    in milliseconds and the Error that should be called when the timeout occurs.
    e.g.:
            def func():
                try:
                    self.con.ping(reconnect=True)
                    return True, None
                except pymysql.err.OperationalError as e:
                    return None, DBConnectionError(e)
            timeout = TimeoutHelper(ping)
            timeout.timer(self.config['timeoutMs'], DBTimeoutError)
    
    The timer() method will return the first value returned from the defined function
    if it is not None of False and raise the second value like an exception. 
    It will also raise the given error when the defined time is over.

    Attributes
    ----------
    daemon : bool
        is true and makes the thread a daemon
    func : function
        the function given to the constructor
    r : any
        the value that gets returned by timer()
    e : Exception
        the exception that gets raised by timer()

    Methods
    -------
    run():
        Overwritten method that gets executed in the thread.
    timer():
        Handles the extra thread and measures the timeout.
    '''
    def __init__(self, func):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon=True
        self.func = func
        self.r = None # values that are returned from func
        self.e = None # errors from func

    def run(self):
        '''Call the given func.'''
        self.r, self.e = self.func()

    def timer(self, timeout, timeout_error):
        '''
        Starts the thread and measures the time for the timeout.
        
        Returns the first returned value of func and raises the second value
        as an exception.

                Parameters:
                        timeout (int) : Timeout length in milliseconds.
                        timeout_error (Exception) : Exception that gets raised when 
                            the timeout is exceeded.
        '''
        self.start()
        t = timeout
        while t > 0:
            if self.e:
                raise self.e
            elif type(self.r) is not NoneType:
                return self.r
            else:
                time.sleep(0.001)
                t -= 1
        else:
            raise timeout_error
```

But I don't know if this works for said input() function.

Answer (score 0):

You're structuring things a bit wrong.

```
running = True

def halt():
    print("Your time has expired!")
    running = False

timer = Timer(5.0, halt), 
timer.start()
while running:
    print("Running!")
    ... # Other things

print("Halting.")
```

The key points are that `Timer` needs to be started before your while loop, or you keep starting it. Secondly, you don't need `cancel()`. Doing so cancels whatever the timer would do when it would expire. Third, the function you call can do more than one thing, including setting the flag for your `While` loop to `False`, or go to another function entirely.

That said, it's unclear if `treading.Timer()` is really meant for this. Typically it's for handling threads, and that's not really what you're doing here. Typically in a game loop you do something like:

```
# Start a clock
# Loop around a set of player actions
#   Check to see how much time has expired at certain checkpoints, quit if it's too much.
# Do something depending on the state when you leave the loop.
```

Comment: Hello thanks but after I modified my code like your code, it didn't work

Comment: @MahyarMohamadpour What does 'didn't work' mean? Did you get an error? How did it behave that you weren't expecting? And how did you actually modify it?

Comment: For again my program when time up didn't end
But it is also possible that I misunderstood and made the wrong changes